# Scroll progres bar hiding text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I want to build a progress bar that indicates the vertical position of the scrollbar. I used this article: https://css-tricks.com/reading-position-indicator/
I made a snippet in order to show you my code.
The result is OK but I want to create a space below the progress bar. Actually, the progress bar hides the content. I tried to solve this problem as you can see by watching the code that I commented, but I was unable to solve my problem. 
Could someone please help me in creating a space below the progress bar ?

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
    var winHeight = $(window).height(),
        docHeight = $("#content").height(),
        progressBar = $('progress'),
        max, value;

    /* Set the max scrollable area */
    max = docHeight - winHeight;
    progressBar.attr('max', max);

    $(document).on('scroll', function() {
        value = $(window).scrollTop();
        progressBar.attr('value', value);
    });
});
$(window).on('resize', function() {
    winHeight = $(window).height(),
        docHeight = $("#content").height();

    max = docHeight - winHeight;
    progressBar.attr('max', max);

    value = $(window).scrollTop();
    progressBar.attr('value', value);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
progress {
  /* Positioning */
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;

  /* Dimensions */
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;

  /* Reset the appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
     -moz-appearance: none;
          appearance: none;

  /* Get rid of the default border in Firefox/Opera. */
  border: none;

  /* Progress bar container for Firefox/IE10+ */
  background-color: transparent;

  /* Progress bar value for IE10+ */
  color: red;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: transparent;
}

progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: red;
}

progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: red;
}
body {
  /*overflow-y: hidden;*/
}

#content {
/*  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body>
    <progress value="0"></progress>
    <div id="content">
    Morbi fermentum quam a dolor cursus malesuada. Quisque eget eleifend velit. Morbi a odio eu lacus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas eget est dictum, luctus augue sed, ultricies odio. Phasellus eget sagittis justo, at vehicula nunc. Nam sit amet felis tincidunt, eleifend mauris ut, accumsan purus. Vivamus interdum dolor pellentesque mauris rutrum, id ornare eros tincidunt. Morbi fermentum quam a dolor cursus malesuada. Quisque eget eleifend velit. Morbi a odio eu lacus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas eget est dictum, luctus augue sed, ultricies odio. Phasellus eget sagittis justo, at vehicula nunc. Nam sit amet felis tincidunt, eleifend mauris ut, accumsan purus. Vivamus interdum dolor pellentesque mauris rutrum, id ornare eros tincidunt.Morbi fermentum quam a dolor cursus malesuada. Quisque eget eleifend velit. Morbi a odio eu lacus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas eget est dictum, luctus augue sed, ultricies odio. Phasellus eget sagittis justo, at vehicula nunc. Nam sit amet felis tincidunt, eleifend mauris ut, accumsan purus. Vivamus interdum dolor pellentesque mauris rutrum, id ornare eros tincidunt.Morbi fermentum quam a dolor cursus malesuada. Quisque eget eleifend velit. Morbi a odio eu lacus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas eget est dictum, luctus augue sed, ultricies odio. Phasellus eget sagittis justo, at vehicula nunc. Nam sit amet felis tincidunt, eleifend mauris ut, accumsan purus. Vivamus interdum dolor pellentesque mauris rutrum, id ornare eros tincidunt.Morbi fermentum quam a dolor cursus malesuada. Quisque eget eleifend velit. Morbi a odio eu lacus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas eget est dictum, luctus augue sed, ultricies odio. Phasellus eget sagittis justo, at vehicula nunc. Nam sit amet felis tincidunt, eleifend mauris ut, accumsan purus. Vivamus interdum dolor pellentesque mauris rutrum, id ornare eros tincidunt. 
  </div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Not too clear on what your trying to do, but a fixed position on an element will always keep it above the content and in that position.

I moved your progress bar into a container and gave that the fixed position with a white background and double the height.

```js
$(document).on('ready', function() {
  var winHeight = $(window).height(),
    docHeight = $("#content").height(),
    progressBar = $('progress'),
    max, value;

  /* Set the max scrollable area */
  max = docHeight - winHeight;
  progressBar.attr('max', max);

  $(document).on('scroll', function() {
    value = $(window).scrollTop();
    progressBar.attr('value', value);
  });
});
$(window).on('resize', function() {
  winHeight = $(window).height(),
    docHeight = $("#content").height();

  max = docHeight - winHeight;
  progressBar.attr('max', max);

  value = $(window).scrollTop();
  progressBar.attr('value', value);
});
```

```css
body {
  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
}
.progress-container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
progress {
  /* Positioning */
  /* Dimensions */
  width: 100%;
  height: 10px;
  /* Reset the appearance */
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  /* Get rid of the default border in Firefox/Opera. */
  border: none;
  /* Progress bar container for Firefox/IE10+ */
  background-color: transparent;
  /* Progress bar value for IE10+ */
  color: red;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-bar {
  background-color: transparent;
}
progress::-webkit-progress-value {
  background-color: red;
}
progress::-moz-progress-bar {
  background-color: red;
}
body {
  /*overflow-y: hidden;*/
}
#content {
  /*  padding-top: 20px;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow-y: auto;*/
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body>
  <div class="progress-container">
    <progress value="0"></progress>
  </div>

  <div id="content">
    Morbi fermentum quam a dolor cursus malesuada. Quisque eget eleifend velit. Morbi a odio eu lacus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas eget est dictum, luctus augue sed, ultricies odio. Phasellus eget sagittis justo, at vehicula nunc. Nam sit amet felis tincidunt,
    eleifend mauris ut, accumsan purus. Vivamus interdum dolor pellentesque mauris rutrum, id ornare eros tincidunt. Morbi fermentum quam a dolor cursus malesuada. Quisque eget eleifend velit. Morbi a odio eu lacus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas eget est
    dictum, luctus augue sed, ultricies odio. Phasellus eget sagittis justo, at vehicula nunc. Nam sit amet felis tincidunt, eleifend mauris ut, accumsan purus. Vivamus interdum dolor pellentesque mauris rutrum, id ornare eros tincidunt.Morbi fermentum
    quam a dolor cursus malesuada. Quisque eget eleifend velit. Morbi a odio eu lacus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas eget est dictum, luctus augue sed, ultricies odio. Phasellus eget sagittis justo, at vehicula nunc. Nam sit amet felis tincidunt, eleifend
    mauris ut, accumsan purus. Vivamus interdum dolor pellentesque mauris rutrum, id ornare eros tincidunt.Morbi fermentum quam a dolor cursus malesuada. Quisque eget eleifend velit. Morbi a odio eu lacus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas eget est dictum,
    luctus augue sed, ultricies odio. Phasellus eget sagittis justo, at vehicula nunc. Nam sit amet felis tincidunt, eleifend mauris ut, accumsan purus. Vivamus interdum dolor pellentesque mauris rutrum, id ornare eros tincidunt.Morbi fermentum quam a
    dolor cursus malesuada. Quisque eget eleifend velit. Morbi a odio eu lacus faucibus facilisis. Maecenas eget est dictum, luctus augue sed, ultricies odio. Phasellus eget sagittis justo, at vehicula nunc. Nam sit amet felis tincidunt, eleifend mauris
    ut, accumsan purus. Vivamus interdum dolor pellentesque mauris rutrum, id ornare eros tincidunt.
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. In fact, I just want to increase the space between the progress par and the content, even when the user scrolls the page. I tried to add a padding-top and margin-top on the content's div but it did not work.